# Start several embedded HornetQ brokers in the same VM

Tags: hornetq

Is there a way to start several HornetQ embedded brokers in the same VM? For instance, two separate applications that run in the same process and are completely unrelated.

This is what I get if I try to register a second `EmbeddedJms` instance while one is already running

> HQ221043: Adding protocol support CORE
>   server: HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.sampleQueue
>   server: HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.topic.sampleTopic
>   server: HQ224000: Failure in initialisation
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HQ119062: Acceptor with id 0 already registered
>       at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMRegistry.registerAcceptor(InVMRegistry.java:36)
>       at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMAcceptor.start(InVMAcceptor.java:104)
>       at org.hornetq.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl.start(RemotingServiceImpl.java:321)
>       at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl.initialisePart2(HornetQServerImpl.java:1725)
>       at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl.access$1400(HornetQServerImpl.java:170)
>       at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl$SharedNothingLiveActivation.run(HornetQServerImpl.java:2700)
>       at org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl.start(HornetQServerImpl.java:450)
>       at org.hornetq.jms.server.impl.JMSServerManagerImpl.start(JMSServerManagerImpl.java:485)

The code that configures the embedded broker can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/hornetq/HornetQAutoConfiguration.java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do that all the time on our testsuite..

on the Connection properties, you can set server-id on the inVM properties.

The connector / acceptor constants would have server-id=1, 2... n on subsequent servers.

look at org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.invm.TransportConstants

Comment: Thanks! For those who are interested by the very precise details of how this would work, [check this commit](https://github.com/snicoll/spring-boot/commit/5325c2663b1f57b32ba7ee2ed850b9aa2bfc66f3) - It also contains new tests that show how to configure that with Spring Boot.